# Ignore all exception from a specific project TEAM-WIZE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2017

We have a project that may generate a lot of exception(because it interacts with a protocol that is widely used but not widely respected).

When it has been implemented, all the "sensitive" methods/constructors were set as `DebuggerStepThrough`.

Since VS2015, the DebuggerStepThrough is now ignored(We now have VS 2017). I know that we can go to the `Exception settings` of Visual Studio, we can specify what kind of exception we want or not, and add conditions with projects types, but this has 2 issues:

1. It's not persisted with the project when we push it to our GIT server
2. We often change those exception settings to track a very particular issue that should not be interrupted, then we reset then, so it would means that we will regularly loose those changes.

So, is there some compilation settings, or any other way to make sure that we don't receive those exception, and that we can share this accross the team(=commit to our git server)?

**NB**: This question is NOT about whether we should handle those exceptions or not.

Answer (score 0):

Would migrating that code to a separate assembly help?  I'm not sure, but you might be able to reference it without pdb's and it should fail silently if you have proper catches in place.

Comment: How would you proceed? This code already has his own project and assembly. Currently I'm referencing it as a project, we could reference it as a DLL, but would you keep the project in the solution?

Comment: Give it its own solution, build it release mode, and put it somewhere by itself without a pdb.  How do you handle third-party DLLs?  Do it like that.  Maybe create a nuget package.